# Java Code Tracing of Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, trace

I'm having trouble with this school work, you have to trace the code of this array using a tracing table, however I am stuck for an answer.

When I go through the code I get to the line where `data[i]` is given the index position of 0, which is `50`. I then get confused as to if the table stops on that line because it cannot proceed because of `data[i]` is not less than `data.length`. So does it end there or am I wrong?

```
public static int ???(int[] data) {

    int result = 1000;

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i] < result) {
            result = data[i];
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

and the data is

> { 50, 43, 22, 30 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)`

You compare `i` with `data.length`, not `data[i]` with `data.length` so your loop run as expected (ie  does not end at i = 0)

Comment: Ah right, you comparing the index position number rather than the actual number that the index position has. Okay cheers!

Answer (score 1):

After the test, what do you think below line of code do?

result = data[i];

Comment: result then becomes the value of data i

Comment: Precisely. It loops till the end. So guess the answer.

Comment: 30. Will be the end result of i and "result" gets the value of 22

Answer (score 0):

The final value of result should `return` 22. This is because the the loop runs from `i < 4`, which means it does not include the `4th` index position in the loop. The final loop ends at the `3rd` index position and since `data[i]` is not greater than result. the `3rd` index is 22 and result is 1000 and since 22 is not greater than 1000, the program returns `22`.